# DisplaySingle.setLcdValueFont has no effect in SteelSeries

Tags: java, swing, steelseries

I am using SteelSeries gauge Java library. In my code DisplaySingle.setLcdValueFont() has no effect: no matter what font I set, the default font is always used. Has anyone managed to make setLcdValueFont work?

Details:
I use DisplaySingle in the following way:

```
public class ScoreDisplay {
private DisplaySingle display = new DisplaySingle();
    public ScoreDisplay() {
        display.setLcdUnitString("");
        Font font =  new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN,30);
        if (font == null) {
            System.out.println("Font is null");
        }
        System.out.println(font.toString());
        display.setLcdValueFont(font);
        display.setLcdColor(LcdColor.AMBER_LCD);
        display.setLcdValue(99);
        display.setLcdDecimals(0);
        display.setLcdValueFont(font);
    }
    public DisplaySingle getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }
}
```

Later in the code, the display gets added to a JPanel:

```
ScoreDisplay scoreDisplay = new ScoreDisplay();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
[...]
panel.add(scoreDisplay.getDisplay());
```

I had a look at the source of DisplaySingle and noticed that its init() method  always resets lcdValueFont to a derivative of LCD_DIGITAL_FONT or LCD_STANDARD_FONT, overwriting value set by a call to .setLcdValueFont. The method init() is called in many places, including various set* methods.

I think there is a bug in DisplaySingle but perhaps I just can't make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug. The font that is set in [setLcdValueFont()](https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Swing/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hansolo/steelseries/gauges/DisplaySingle.java#L946) gets overridden in [init()](https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Swing/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hansolo/steelseries/gauges/DisplaySingle.java#L269) method to default `LCD_STANDARD_FONT` font. Here is that line:

```
lcdValueFont = LCD_STANDARD_FONT.deriveFont(0.625f * getInnerBounds().height);
```

So it is always `Verdana 24`. You should be able to change units font, though.